# Cause-specific mortality (or survival) analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, survival

I am looking for the statistical test that shows the significant contribution of one factor to the overall rate (cause and death rate). Our study is about the number of people who died from year 2008 to 2012 and the cause of death. What test am I going to use to know the individual contribution of the causes to the total number of death?

Answer (score 1):

> What test am I going to use to know the individual contribution of the causes to the total number of death?

That would be *estimation* rather than testing.

Specifically, the individual contributions would be based on some [point estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_estimator), or possibly an interval estimate [such as a confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval).

[Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) would be used to see if specific contributions were different from some null value (such as seeing whether contributions were different from that attributable to just random noise, perhaps).

More information would help guide a better answer.

Comment: @ttnphns added very brief discussion with links, in the hopes that the OP will either clarify or ask a followup.

Comment: How am I going to solve my problem using regression? My data are the following:

Comment: thanks for your answer. how can I solve my problem through the use of regression analysis?

Answer (score 1):

When your dependent variable is a count (as, here, number of dead) you want some form of count regression; here the likeliest seem Poisson or negative binomial regression. You then can have various factors as independent variables.

However, if you already have the cause of death for each person, you don't need regression, just proportions, if each death has only one cause.

Comment: Presumably many people survived through the short period of study, wouldn't one need to employee a model that accounts for censored individuals?

Comment: That depends on what one wants to estimate... Number of dead or time to death